# Setting Content-Type / application/json in header

Tags: python, json, content-type

I'm using urllib2 to create an HTTP request, I need to set Content-Type : application/json in the header, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, data='\"type\":\"chain\",\"data\":null')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % creds)
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
request.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
print "Data: %s" % request.get_data()
print "Accept: %s" % request.get_header("Accept")
print "Content-Type: %s" % request.get_header("Content-Type")
print "Authorization: %s" % request.get_header("Authorization")
```

The results are:

Data: "type":"chain","data":null

Accept: application/json

**Content-Type: None**

Authorization: Basic U1lTQ1RMOmFiYzEyMw==

As you can see, even though I'm setting "Content Type", its coming back "None".

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That's because of an inconsistency in the `urllib2.Request` header accessor methods - namely, `add_header()` auto-capitalizes your header when storing, but `get_header()` doesn't do the same when retrieving, so if you do:

```
print "Content-Type: %s" % request.get_header("Content-type")
```

or

```
print "Content-Type: %s" % request.get_header("Content-Type".capitalize())
```

everything should show up fine. Headers, by all HTTP specifications, should be treated as case-insensitive anyway, sadly most HTTP libraries out there doesn't respect that fact.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine that add_header() method didn't like "Type" being capitalized, changing it to request.add_header("Content-type", "application/json") solved the problem.